# Reason for Jump proceeded by a NoOperation instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

Well, me and a friend are working on a project and we ran into a near jump followed by a nop.... is there a reason for taking a break right after calling something?

The nop is at the end of the code, would it prepare the processor for idle?

Comment: what architecture? Without that fact we're all guessing.

Comment: Clarify - Is it a jump or a call, and was the nop before or after?

Answer (score 3):

Is it actually a short jump that has been encoded as a near jump?

If so, the short jump (3 bytes) will be padded in the third byte.  If at the time of encoding, the assembler knows the jump location of a short jump is really a near jump, it will code it as a near jump. But having already reserved 3 bytes for the short jump, it will need to pad with a NOP.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the assembler architecture, it could be there to align the following function's address, or it could be to protect against the next instruction being run ( I believe MIPS does this).  You'll also sometimes see a nop and a bunch of random data after functions that are used for local memory pools (ARM).

Comment: SPARC had *branch delay instructions*.

Comment: intel X86, actually 286 to be exact, using MASM syntax.

Comment: Then it's either function instruction alignment, or the short jump vs near jump explanation of @Mitch (I bow to his superior psychic ability)